# Everything after question mark ? disappears in URL (Wordpress) SOLVED

Tags: php, wordpress, url, parameters, query-string

My website (6.1.1 Wordpress) removes anything in the url after a ? is inserted. I use this for passing GET variables from PHP to the website (display notifications and such). https://www.example.com/?msg=Welcome redirects to https://www.example.com/.

And this happens when manually pasting the URL into a browser so it isn't a PHP issue.

I have tried adding Rewrite conditions and such to .htaccess, and also resetting the entire file, still same outcome. I tried disabling all plugins, I tried updating PHP. I just can't find a solution.

The weird thing is, the URL keeps the variable within the URL when I'm signed in as an admin.

I use plugin All in One SEO which has a redirections tab but only for premium users (disabling the plugin doesn't stop the URL parameter removal).

All I'm trying to ask is, is there a file that could've been changed by a plugin that can cause this? I want to find that file and just delete it, or update it so it doesn't remove the URL parameters. Please, it's such a simple fix that I can't find and it's driving me nuts.

Why is URL parameter getting removed for everyone but me (signed in as Admin). It just makes 0 sense. Fresh browsers with no cache or anything also remove the string upon pressing Enter. Almost before the site is even loading!

```
SOLUTION
```

This is extremely weird, but the All In One SEO Plugin was causing the issue after all. However, disabling it or deleting it wouldn't solve the problem. The only specific way it worked for me was to disable ALL of my plugins, and re-enable all of them EXCEPT the All In One SEO plugin. Boom. Solved. JESUST that took long.

sorry for not following the correct format.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include a solution. Post it as an answer instead

Comment: We're experiencing the same issue - were you able to keep using AIOSEO or find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve issue (from AIOSEO support)

Go to All in One SEO > Search Appearance > Advanced tab, disable (if enabled) the Remove Query Args feature under Crawl Cleanup and Save Changes